# What is missing in this Swift name macro for a bridged Objective-C method?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, bridging

Xcode reports this warning:

> parameter of 'swift_name' attribute must be a Swift function name string"

For the following function. I do not know what I wrote incorrectly.

```
+ (CGFloat *)feedDetailWithUpdate:(PostUpdate *)update
                     trackingInfo:(nullable TrackingInfo *)trackingInfo
              highlightedComments:(NSArray<FeedComment *> *)highlightedComments
NS_SWIFT_NAME(feedDetailWithUpdate(update:trackingInfo:highlightedComments));
```

Answer (score 9):

I figured it out, there was a colon missing at the end of the argument list:

```
NS_SWIFT_NAME(feedDetailWithUpdate(update:trackingInfo:highlightedComments:));
```